# How to add logs to newrelic in nodejs

Tags: node.js, newrelic

I have a Kafka consumer topic, where I am able to get the data from the topic. But I wanted to add the newrelic for the topic.

How can I write to manually send the events to newrelic.

I have a newrelic.js file and I have configured it, but I have read that for Kafka I need to write manually the events.

Sample Code Snippet

```
const newrelic = require('newrelic'); 
const config = require('./config')
const topicConfig = require('./topicConfig')
const scheduler = require("../scheduler");
const Kafka = require("node-rdkafka");
const defaultConfig = {...config}
const topicConf = {...topicConfig}


try {
  var topic = new Kafka.KafkaConsumer(
    defaultConfig,
    topicConf,
    {}
  );
  topic.connect();

  logger.info(
    "topic object",
    topic
  );
  topic
    .on("ready", function () {
      topic.subscribe([config.topicConf]);
      topic.consume();
    })
    .on("data", function (data) {
      scheduler.handleMessage(data.value);
    })
    .on("error", function (err) {
      logger.error("Error in topic consumer ", err);
    });
} catch (error) {
  logger.error(
    "Exception while connecting to kafka",
    error
  );
}
```

How can I add the manual events to newrelic? Which events to use, like these below were mentioned on doc, but confused, How to integrate and where to add inside this try catch block.

Example methods as in the docs:

```
newrelic.setTransactionName(name)
newrelic.setControllerName(name, [action])
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define custom event something like this. Pass the event to addPageAction custom event.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
document.getElementById('btnFndCntnt').addEventListener('click',function (e) {
            newrelic.addPageAction('Find');
    })
});
```

Comment: But the code is on node js, didn't understood how these we can write